# Получение головы и хвоста списка

Tags: lua, списки, функциональное-программирование

```
function cons(_x, _y)
return function(m) return (m == 0 and _x) or _y end end


function head(list)
    return (list ~= nil and list(0))
            or nil end


    function tail(list)
    return (list ~= nil and list(1))
            or nil end 
    -- Собираем список в строку
function list2str(list)
    return (tail(list) ~= nil and head(list) .. ', ' .. list2str(tail(list)))
            or head(list)
end

-- Собираем список из параметров функции
function make_list(head, ...)
    return (... ~= nil and cons(head,make_list(...)))
            or cons(head, nil)
    end
-- Переворачиваем список
function reverse_list(list)
    return reverse_acc( list, nil )
end
-- Сервисная функция с аккумулятором для переворота списка
function reverse_acc(list, acc)
    return  (tail(list) ~= nil and
                reverse_acc( tail(list), cons( head(list), acc ) ) )
              or cons( head(list), acc )
end

-- Получаем каждый второй элемент списка. От index зависит,
--      будут ли это чётные или нечётные элементы
function get_sublist(list, index)
    return (tail(list) ~= nil and
              (index == 1 and
                  cons( head(list), get_sublist( tail(list), 0))
              or
                  get_sublist( tail(list), 1) ) )
            or (index == 1 and
                  cons(head(list), nil) )
                or nil
end

-- Получаем нечётные елементы списка
function get_odd(list)
    return get_sublist(list, 1)
end

-- Получаем чётные елементы списка
function get_even(list)
    return get_sublist(list, 0)
end

-- Собираем в один два списка {a1, a2, ...} и {b1, b2, ...}
--    по принципу: {a1, b1, a2, b2, ...}
function megre_lists(list1, list2)
    return (tail(list1)  ~= nil and
              cons( head(list1), cons( head(list2), megre_lists( tail(list1), tail(list2) ))))
            or
              cons( head(list1), head(list2) ~= nil and
                                    cons( head(list2),nil)
                                 or
                                    nil)
end

function main_task(list)
  -- Печать первоначального списка
  print( list2str(list) )

  -- Тестирование функции переворачивания списка
  print( list2str(reverse_list(list)) )

  -- Тестирование получения нечётных элементов
  print( list2str(get_odd(list)) )

  -- Тестирование получения чётных элементов
  print( list2str(get_even(list)) )

  -- Получаем список нечётных элементов, переворачиваем его и сливаем со списком
  --  чётных элементов
  print ( list2str(
                    megre_lists(
                                reverse_list( get_odd(list) ),
                                get_even(list) ) ) )
end

main_task( make_list(unpack( {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} )) )
```

Получение головы и хвоста для работы со списком в функциональном стиле. Вопрос: что есть такое (0) и (1)? Не понимаю что это и как это работает (с логикой все ясно. Непонятно как работают эти загадочные, для меня, 0 и 1)

Comment: в примере не хватает определения функции list

Comment: дополнил первый пост

Comment: везде передается list в качестве аргумента, но не  ясно, что это такое, по всей видимости это функция, дайте ее определение, будет ясно почему 0 и 1.

Comment: Не увидел определение list как функции. Дополнил пример полностью.

Comment: список лист получается как результат make_list() , каждый элемент этого списка - как результат функции cons(), которая возвращает функцию. вот правда не ясно, чему там равно m..

Comment: разобрался с m - [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726848/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас тут такой странный тип данных, который мы называем функциональным. Это не структура из двух элементов, это функция, которая возвращает одно или второе значение. Если на вход подаём 0, то возвращается первое значение _x, если 1 (или что-то другое), то возвращается второе значение _y.

Важно понять, что пара -- это не данные, это функция, которая возвращает данные. Если мы на базе пары делаем список, то в _x будет первое значение из списка, а в _y -- весь остальной список.

Например, функция `head` получает на вход такую функцию и возвращает первый элемент пары `list(0)`. Функция `tail` тоже получает на вход функцию, но возвращает второй элемент (весь остальной список) `list(1)`.

```
function head(list)
    return (list ~= nil and list(0))
            or nil end


function tail(list)
    return (list ~= nil and list(1))
            or nil end
```

P.S. Спрашивали бы вы в том самом ответе, и не плодили бы вопросы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/682656/255365

Comment: Спасибо , Руслан, все становится понятнее, однако что есть эти 0 и 1? Это аргументы к аргументу (list) (пока не встречалось подобное)

Comment: Весь ответ находится тут: `function(m) return (m == 0 and _x) or _y end` Это и есть функция, которая изображает из себя структуру на два элемента. Именно эта функция получает на вход 0 или 1 и выдаёт _x или _y. Это таш функциональный тип данных. Представьте, что это массив с индексами 0 и 1. Передаёте индекс -- получаете данные из соответствующей ячейки.

Comment: `list = function(m) return (m == 0 and 111) or 222 end`

`print (list(0))`

`print (list(1))`

Comment: Да, я очень благодарен вам за ответ. Он правда проясняет многое и как это работает стало ясно, но что есть 0 и 1 для аргумента list? list - это аргумент, а 0 и 1 к этому аргументу... проще говоря, как они называются? Что это? Индексы, для того, что бы просто отличаться друг от друга, дополнительные аргументы с которыми передается аргумент?

Comment: В функцию `head` передаётся аргумент `list`. Значение этого аргумента -- функция. В эту функцию можно передать аргумент и вызвать её. Именно это мы и делаем. Передаём в качестве аргумента 0 или 1 в функцию, которая содержится в переменной `list`. Очевидно, вам тяжело разобраться с функциональным подходом к данным. Попробуйте почитать "Структура и интерпретация компьютерных программ". Книга лежит в интернете в открытом доступе.